# Use Groupby / Interpolate in Rust Polars

Tags: rust, rust-polars

I'm working on a little utility app, coming from python/pandas and trying to rebuild some basic tools that can be distributed via executables. I'm having a hard time interpreting the documentation for what seems like it should be a fairly simple process of reading some raw data, resampling it based on the datetime column, and then interpolating it to fill in missing data as necessary.

My cargo.toml looks like:

```
[dependencies]
polars = "0.19.0"
```

And the code I've written so far is:

```
use polars::prelude::*;
use std::fs::File;

fn main() {
    let mut df = CsvReader::new("raw.csv".into())
        .finish();

    //interpolate to clean up blank/nan
    //resample/groupby 15Min-1D using mean, blank/nan if missing
    
    let mut file = File::create("final.csv").expect("File not written!!!");

    CsvWriter::new(&mut file)
        .has_header(true)
        .with_delimiter(b',')
        .finish(&df);

}
```

and the raw.csv data might look like:

```
site,datetime,val1,val2,val3,val4,val5,val6
XX1,2021-01-01 00:45,,,,4.60,,
XX1,2021-01-01 00:50,,,,2.30,,
XX1,2021-01-01 00:53,21.90,16.00,77.67,3.45,1027.20,0.00
XX1,2021-01-01 01:20,,,,4.60,,
XX1,2021-01-01 01:53,21.90,16.00,77.67,3.45,1026.90,0.00
XX1,2021-01-01 01:55,,,,0.00,,
XX1,2021-01-01 02:00,,,,0.00,,
XX1,2021-01-01 02:45,,,,5.75,,
XX1,2021-01-01 02:50,,,,8.05,,
XX1,2021-01-01 02:53,21.00,16.00,80.69,8.05,1026.80,0.00
```

But I can't seem to call the methods because I get errors like:

```
method not found in `Result<DataFrame, PolarsError>`
```

or

```
expected struct `DataFrame`, found enum `Result`
```

and I'm not sure how to properly shift between classes.

I've tried obviously wrong answers like:

```
let grouped = df.lazy().groupby_dynamic("datetime", "1h").agg("datetime", mean());
```

but basically, I'm looking for the polars equivalent of pandas code:

```
df = df.interpolate()
df = df.resample(sample_frequency).mean()
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What's an example of code that causes an error message like that?

Comment: @SolomonUcko - if I added any methods to df I'd get "method not found in `Result<DataFrame, PolarsError>`". I found that if I added ".unwrap()" after ".finish()" I'd get a dataframe object (?) rather than a result object.

For "expected struct `DataFrame`, found enum `Result`", I get that at the end when I tried to write the df to the CsvWriter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of how you might:

- **upsample** via a left join on a date range
- filling missing values with **interpolate**
- **downsample** via a **groupby_dynamic**

```rust
use chrono::prelude::*;
use polars::prelude::*;
use polars_core::time::*;
use std::io::Cursor;
use polars::frame::groupby::DynamicGroupOptions;

fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let csv = "site,datetime,val1,val2,val3,val4,val5,val6
XX1,2021-01-01 00:45,,,,4.60,,
XX1,2021-01-01 00:50,,,,2.30,,
XX1,2021-01-01 00:53,21.90,16.00,77.67,3.45,1027.20,0.00
XX1,2021-01-01 01:20,,,,4.60,,
XX1,2021-01-01 01:53,21.90,16.00,77.67,3.45,1026.90,0.00
XX1,2021-01-01 01:55,,,,0.00,,
XX1,2021-01-01 02:00,,,,0.00,,
XX1,2021-01-01 02:45,,,,5.75,,
XX1,2021-01-01 02:50,,,,8.05,,
XX1,2021-01-01 02:53,21.00,16.00,80.69,8.05,1026.80,0.00
";
    let cursor = Cursor::new(csv);

    // prefer scan csv when your data is not in memory
    let mut df = CsvReader::new(cursor).finish()?;
    df.try_apply("datetime", |s| {
        s.utf8()?
            .as_datetime(Some("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"), TimeUnit::Nanoseconds)
            .map(|ca| ca.into_series())
    })?;
    
    // now we take the datetime column and extract timestamps from them
    // with these timestamps we create a `date_range` with an interval of 1 minute
    let dt = df.column("datetime")?;

    let timestamp = dt.cast(&DataType::Int64)?;
    let timestamp_ca = timestamp.i64()?;

    let first = timestamp_ca.get(0).unwrap();
    let last = timestamp_ca.get(timestamp_ca.len() - 1).unwrap();

    let range = date_range(
        first,
        last,
        Duration::parse("1m"),
        ClosedWindow::Both,
        "date_range",
        TimeUnit::Nanoseconds,
    );
    let range_df = DataFrame::new(vec![range.into_series()])?;

    // now that we got the date_range we use it to upsample the dataframe.
    // after that we interpolate the missing values
    // and then we groupby in a fixed time interval to get more regular output
    let out = range_df
        .lazy()
        .join(
            df.lazy(),
            [col("date_range")],
            [col("datetime")],
            JoinType::Left,
        )
        .select([col("*").interpolate()])
        .groupby_dynamic([], DynamicGroupOptions {
            index_column: "date_range".into(),
            every: Duration::parse("15m"),
            period: Duration::parse("15m"),
            offset: Duration::parse("0m"),
            truncate: true,
            include_boundaries: false,
            closed_window: ClosedWindow::Left,
        }).agg([col("*").first()])
        .collect()?;

    dbg!(out);

    Ok(())
}
```

These are the features I used:

```
["csv-file", "pretty_fmt", "temporal", "dtype-date", "dtype-datetime", "lazy", "interpolate", "dynamic_groupby"]
```

### Output

This ouputs

```
[src/main.rs:68] out = shape: (9, 9)
┌─────────────────────┬─────────────────────┬────────────┬────────────┬─────┬────────────┬────────────┬─────────────┬────────────┐
│ date_range          ┆ date_range_first    ┆ site_first ┆ val1_first ┆ ... ┆ val3_first ┆ val4_first ┆ val5_first  ┆ val6_first │
│ ---                 ┆ ---                 ┆ ---        ┆ ---        ┆     ┆ ---        ┆ ---        ┆ ---         ┆ ---        │
│ datetime[ns]        ┆ datetime[ns]        ┆ str        ┆ f64        ┆     ┆ f64        ┆ f64        ┆ f64         ┆ f64        │
╞═════════════════════╪═════════════════════╪════════════╪════════════╪═════╪════════════╪════════════╪═════════════╪════════════╡
│ 2021-01-01 00:45:00 ┆ 2021-01-01 00:45:00 ┆ XX1        ┆ null       ┆ ... ┆ null       ┆ 4.6        ┆ null        ┆ null       │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2021-01-01 01:00:00 ┆ 2021-01-01 01:00:00 ┆ null       ┆ 21.9       ┆ ... ┆ 77.67      ┆ 4.6        ┆ 1027.165    ┆ 0.0        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2021-01-01 01:15:00 ┆ 2021-01-01 01:15:00 ┆ null       ┆ 21.9       ┆ ... ┆ 77.67      ┆ 4.6        ┆ 1027.09     ┆ 0.0        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2021-01-01 01:30:00 ┆ 2021-01-01 01:30:00 ┆ null       ┆ 21.9       ┆ ... ┆ 77.67      ┆ 4.251515   ┆ 1027.015    ┆ 0.0        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ ...                 ┆ ...                 ┆ ...        ┆ ...        ┆ ... ┆ ...        ┆ ...        ┆ ...         ┆ ...        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2021-01-01 02:00:00 ┆ 2021-01-01 02:00:00 ┆ XX1        ┆ 21.795     ┆ ... ┆ 78.022333  ┆ 0.0        ┆ 1027.153333 ┆ 0.0        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2021-01-01 02:15:00 ┆ 2021-01-01 02:15:00 ┆ null       ┆ 21.57      ┆ ... ┆ 78.777333  ┆ 4.983333   ┆ 1027.053333 ┆ 0.0        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2021-01-01 02:30:00 ┆ 2021-01-01 02:30:00 ┆ null       ┆ 21.345     ┆ ... ┆ 79.532333  ┆ 5.366667   ┆ 1026.953333 ┆ 0.0        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2021-01-01 02:45:00 ┆ 2021-01-01 02:45:00 ┆ XX1        ┆ 21.12      ┆ ... ┆ 80.287333  ┆ 5.75       ┆ 1026.853333 ┆ 0.0        │
└─────────────────────┴─────────────────────┴────────────┴────────────┴─────┴────────────┴────────────┴─────────────┴────────────┘
```

Note that `polars_core` also is needed for the time module, this will be exported to polars next patch.

Comment: Why are there nulls in the first row ? Shouldn't the interpolate fill those ?

Comment: It interpolates between values. If the first value is missing it can not be interpolated. That would be extrapolation.

Comment: Of course. I was being dumb. My excuse is I was working too late. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
use polars::prelude::*;
use std::fs::File;

fn main() {
    let mut df = CsvReader::new("raw.csv".into())
        .finish()
        .unwrap();

    //interpolate to clean up blank/nan
    //resample/groupby 15Min-1D using mean, blank/nan if missing
    
    let mut file = File::create("final.csv").expect("File not written!!!");

    CsvWriter::new(&mut file)
        .has_header(true)
        .with_delimiter(b',')
        .finish(&df)
        .unwrap();

}
```

In general, if you get an error about `Result`, try adding `.unwrap()` or `.expect(...)`.

Comment: Right, I had figured out the unwrap part as I mentioned in my comment, but I really need help actually interpolating and resampling. It appears that maybe interpolating is just a series method at the moment? And I'm not sure how to use the groupby function to resample either. 

I know both can be done because they're available in the python implementation, but the documentation is unclear for me on the rust side...

Comment: @EricO Ah, got it. For interpolating you could try [`fill_null`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/polars/frame/struct.DataFrame.html#method.fill_null) or [`interpolate`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/polars/prelude/trait.Interpolate.html), for resampling you could try [`sample_frac`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/polars/frame/struct.DataFrame.html#method.sample_frac) or [`sample_n`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/polars/frame/struct.DataFrame.html#method.sample_n), and for mean you could try [`mean`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/polars/frame/struct.DataFrame.html#method.mean).

Comment: To use [`Interpolate::interpolate`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/polars/prelude/trait.Interpolate.html) or [`ChunkedArray::interpolate`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/polars/chunked_array/struct.ChunkedArray.html#impl-Interpolate), try also using [`DataFrame::column`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/polars/prelude/struct.DataFrame.html#method.column) and [`SeriesTrait::f64`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/polars/series/trait.SeriesTrait.html#method.f64) (or the corresponding method for the data type).